# SpringBoot - Deactivate security completely to enable digest forwarding

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proxy, digest-authentication

We are building an app based on SpringBoot that shall work like a proxy. It accepts requests and sends them to another endpoint. This includes the digest authentication.

`Client --> Proxy (Spring) --> Resource`

The client and resource use digest authentication, which works fine without the proxy.

How can I **completely** disable **any** security, but especially springs default handling of digest authentication, to plainly forward the request (no need to discuss potential security issues, this is intended).

We tried `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()`, `security.ignored=/**`, `management.security.enabled=false` and

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

I tested that digest forwarding is technically on a NodeJS/Express stack.

Comment: Remove the spring security dependencies, security will only be enabled if those jars are on the class path. If you don't need security remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ignore any request. Also, you have to remove, if exists, the servlet's filters over digest.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
}
```

Comment: "servlet's filters over digest" - do you mean filters we added or are there any default digest filters?

Comment: There were no default filters preventing this :)